# Can we control the ID that will be appended to a web api and hash it before the call?

Tags: javascript, c#, api

Let's say we have this controller: ChatController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ChatController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet("{id}")]
  public ActionResult<JArray> Get(int id)
  {
    try
    { ... }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { ... }
  }
}
```

In javascript I am calling the Api like:

```
var Chat = function (urlID) {
  var config = {
      "url": "/api/Chat/"+ urlID,
      "method": "GET",
      "timeout": 0,
      "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
  };
  $.ajax(config).done(function (response) { ... });
}
```

Can I change the ID to a Guid in the background when someone appends an integer to the API before running the Controller code; knowing that I have a function that converts integers to Guids by looking up in a table at the database.
I know this might sound confusing but please let me know if anyone have an idea, that would be appreciated.

In the Network Tab I want to users only see the Guid and not the integers even if the url have an integer as ID

Comment: having two different sets of IDs is a _terrible_ design choice. also: _why_ do you not want the int-ID to be seen?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I know but the problem I have is that my api and webpage are being called and imbed inside an iframe by another Website, and the only way they can call my api is by appending integers. Now the problem is when you go to their website and inspect and view the Network Tab they can see the ID appended to the api calls let's say '11' that makes the ID's predictable and any one can try any numbers and get to the data if that makes sense!

Comment: i do not see how that in any way forces you to use ints beside or instead of GUIDs. if you're restricted to purely numeric values, then a) you can't really send hashes, anyway, and b) _could_ transfer your GUID converted as BigInteger. and if the "other website" can only embed your app via a numeric ID, then hiding that ID in the network tab is moot, since a malevolent user can just, you know.. inspect the iframe. my suggestion? a) just switch to 100% GUID and let _them_ worry about using it, or add better protection than "hiding and hoping" to any actually sensitive data.